# Let $K$ be a field and $O_K$ be it's ring of integers. $I$ be fractional ideal of $O_K$. Why $O_K=${$α\in K \mid αI⊆I$}?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a field and $O_K$ be its ring of integers.
$I$ be fractional ideal of $O_K$.

Why $O_K=${$α\in K \mid αI⊆I$} ?

I think one inclusion ⊆ is obvious because $I$ is $O_K$ submodule of $K$.
But I'm stuck with the other inclusion ⊇.

Comment: Think in terms of factorizations into prime ideals with both positive and negative exponents. The factorization of $(\alpha)$ cannot contain any primes raised to a negative power, or the result would not be a multiple of $I$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $K$ is a number field.

- Show that $O_K$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}$-module, whence so is $I$.
- Taking a $\Bbb{Z}$-basis of $I$ then (the multiplication by) $\alpha$ becomes an endomorphism $A$ of $\Bbb{Z}^n$.
- Every such endomorphism is integral, ie. $A$ is a root of a monic integer polynomial, and so is $\alpha$, ie. $\alpha\in O_K$.